# i am getting this error some time while running android app on android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I am getting this error while running the app.And this happens only few times.i am not getting what is causing problem.Can anybody provide me solution?the error is given below.

```
'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

and my build.gragle file
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

```
}


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.eagleeye.retailapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled true
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
compile files('libs/acra-4.6.1.jar')
compile files('libs/itext-pdfa-5.5.6.jar')
compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.5.6.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-3.11-20141221.jar')
compile files('libs/ProwessPride_V1.01.jar')
compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.2.6'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
```

}

and my java runtime environment is set to java1.8.0
Please somebody help me.I am having a deployment date near.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dexOptions { incremental true javaMaxHeapSize "4g"}
```

This solve my problem.Put this in gradle.build

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once and it was caused by exceeding the 65K methods dex limit.
Try to clean your project and remove unused libraries.

Comment: i am having question.If their is limit why its building successfully .BTW their are no 65 k methods in my project.

Comment: The 65k method limit is application wide, meaning everything you include in your gradle build file also count toward the method limit. The limit is in affect when generating the apk file, not when just compiling the project.